# Manage launch screen at the time of local notification arrive

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am giving short intro of my app. In my app I have to put 6 images on screen and user can select any one image from them, also user can set it's alarm by using local notification. When notification is arrive and click on banner/alert button at that time this selected image will be display on the screen with back button.
This back button bring to main screen *(which has images and set alarm facility)*.

So, my problem is when I get notification and I clicked on banner then first launch scree are displayed and then selected image, this is looking very awkward. I want to only display my selected image at the time of got notification *(not launch screen)*. 
How can I do this ? I am thinking about set selected image as launch scren when notification is arrive and then after set launch image as default/old one but  I heard that we can not change launch image because it's fixed image file in the bundle.

So, please give me your suggestion.

**NOTE:** I did it all such like get selected image when my notification is arrive, etc. I have just issue about launch screen and selected image. here launch screen displaying first then after I can display my selected image, Is there any way to display my selected image first rather then launch screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
I want to only display my selected image at the time of got notification. 
How can I do this ?
```

You can Add an `NSDictionary` object with your `UILocalNotification` like

```
notification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"yourImageName.png" 
forKey:@"imageKey"];
```

And the fetch it from your `UILocalNotification` objects. So this will help you to detect the image that user selected at the time of setting notification.

```
I am thinking about set selected image as launch scren
```

The Lunch/default image for an `iOS` app must be a fixed image file in your bundle. You cannot change it programmatically .

```
the time of got notification (not launch screen).
```

As we know the launch image is a simple placeholder image that iOS displays when your app starts up mainly cover the start time for users impression that your app is fast and responsive so i do't think so you can achieve this.

Comment: I already did it.. please read my question.. i have issue about launch screen and this selected image

Comment: Thanks mate for your replay, please read my note for more understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this

```
UILocalNotification *lclNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
lclNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
lclNotification.alertBody = @"test test test";
lclNotification.alertLaunchImage = @"default_chat_background_new.jpg";
NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
lclNotification.fireDate = date;
[application scheduleLocalNotification:lclNotification];
```

Comment: your answer is you cannot remove lunch screen as when your app starts it cover the start time.

Comment: You can set alert launch image, so as soon as you open app from your local notification it shows your custom launch image rather then your app launch image.

Comment: set lclNotification.alertLaunchImage = @"your new launch image save in bundle"

Comment: @Ramansoni - alertLaunchImage it's away some but it only worked for bundle image >> :(

Comment: Yes.. This is iOS limitation.. you can't have runtime images as launch screen :(